# Python code - not sure about text files

Tags: python

I need help with my python code. I've been trying to save the sentence inputted into a text file without it repeating the words in the file. I'm not sure how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
import sys

#user-friendly, informs the user what do to
answer = input("What is your name?\n")
print("Hello " + answer + " and welcome to this program!\n")
print("This program will ask you for a sentence and print out the positions of the words instead of the actual words. it will then save it in a file with the sentence.\n")

repeat = True
loop = True
true = True

#Allows the user to decide whether or not they want to use the program
while repeat:
    answer2 = input("Do you want to do run this program?\n")
    #if the answer is 'no' then the program stops
    if answer2.lower() == "No" or answer2.lower() == "nah" or answer2.lower() == "no" or answer2.lower() == "n":
        print ("Okay then ... Bye.")
        sys.exit()
    #if the answer is 'yes' then the code continues
    elif answer2 == "Yes".lower() or answer2.lower() == "yeah" or answer2.lower() == "yes" or answer2.lower() == "y":
        print ("Okay then ... \n")
        while true:
            if loop == True:
                sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:\n").lower()
            #converts the sentence into a list
            s = sentence.split()
            #works out the positions of the words
            positions = [s.index(x)+1 for x in s]
            print(positions)

            #opens a text file
            fi = open("CA Task 2.txt", "w")
            #Allows you to write over  the original content in the file
            fi.write(str(s))
            #it closes the file once you've finished with it
            fi.close()

            #opens a text file
            fi = open("CA Task 2.txt", "a")
            #Allows you to add to the text file instead of writing over it
            fi.write("\n")
            fi.write(str(positions))
            #it closes the file once you've finished with it
            fi.close()
            sys.exit()

    #if the answer is neither 'yes' nor 'no' then the programs jumps to this part and allows the user to try again
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid answer! Try again!\n")
```

Let's just say the sentence inputted is "ask not what your country can do for you but what you can do for your country".

It should come up saying:
ask not what your country can do for you but what you can do for your country

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5]

This works and then it has to be saved into a text file:
['ask', 'not', 'what', 'your', 'country', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'you', 'but', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'your', 'country']

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5]

This is fine but what i want it to do is to not repeat the word if it has already been mentioned once in the text file.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for help with here. What are you expecting - maybe an example of user input and what would be saved in the file would be handy. And what is currently happening.

Comment: Basically i want the user to input a sentence (this works) and then i want to save it in a text file with the positions (this also works). But what i don't know what to do if a word in the sentence is repeated how do you keep that out of the text file @freebie

Comment: @AsifKhan, Can you add your expected answer in your question? it can be image or text which will help to understand your question.

Comment: I've changed it @RuhulAmin

Comment: @AsifKhan, See my answer now

Comment: Tangental tip: you can make your if statements a bit more readable using the `in` operator for a membership test. e.g. `if answer.lower() in ['no', 'nah', 'n']:`

Comment: @AsifKhan, Please accept the answer which helped you to help the community. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is built is function called: `set` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set:

```
import sys

 #user-friendly, informs the user what do to
 answer = input("What is your name?\n")
 print("Hello " + answer + " and welcome to this program!\n")
 print("This program will ask you for a sentence and print out the positions of the words instead of the actual words. it will then save it in a file with the sentence.\n")

repeat = True
loop = True
true = True

 #Allows the user to decide whether or not they want to use the program
 while repeat:
  answer2 = input("Do you want to do run this program?\n")
  #if the answer is 'no' then the program stops
  if answer2.lower() == "No" or answer2.lower() == "nah" or answer2.lower() ==    "no" or answer2.lower() == "n":
    print ("Okay then ... Bye.")
    sys.exit()
#if the answer is 'yes' then the code continues
elif answer2 == "Yes".lower() or answer2.lower() == "yeah" or answer2.lower() == "yes" or answer2.lower() == "y":
    print ("Okay then ... \n")
    while true:
        if loop == True:
            sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:\n").lower()
        # converts the sentence into a list
        s = sentence.split()
        # for loop makes sure that if the word is in the list then it wont print it out again
        for word in s:
            if word not in s:
                s.append(word)
        # works out the positions of the words
        positions = [s.index(x) + 1 for x in s]
        print(set(positions))

        # opens a text file
        fi = open("CA Task 2.txt", "w")
        # Allows you to write over  the original content in the file
        fi.write(str(set(s)))
        # it closes the file once you've finished with it
        fi.close()

        # opens a text file
        fi = open("CA Task 2.txt", "a")
        # Allows you to add to the text file instead of writing over it
        fi.write("\n")
        fi.write(str(set(positions)))
        # it closes the file once you've finished with it
        fi.close()
        sys.exit()

        #if the answer is neither 'yes' nor 'no' then the programs jumps to this part and allows the user to try again
        else:
         print("Please enter a valid answer! Try again!\n")'
```

Answer (score 2):

So it's your for loop section that's not behaving? Looks to me as you are splitting a sentence into a list so `['here', 'is', 'my', 'sentence', 'input']` and then looping through each of those words and appending them back to the list if they aren't already in it. So this should never have any effect on `s`.

Python has a `set` collection which holds unique values. So it's like a `list` but doesn't let you add duplicates. You could use this instead of your for loop as you can initialise a `set` with a `list` - like the one use are creating from your `split()` call.

```
s = sentence.split()
s = set(s)
```

Edit: sets do not preserve order like a `list`. So if saving the words in order of first appearance is important then this method won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for word in s:
    if word not in s:
        s.append(word)
```

doesn't make sense to me. Are you trying to create a list of unique words? It gives you the same list.

Also `if answer2.lower() == "No"` is superfluos, as the result would never be 'No'.

Let's say, you have a list from a sentence where some words are unique, and some are not: 
`s = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'spam']`
and you want to get the digital representation of these unique words, you can get it like that:

```
d = []
i = 0
for item in s:
    if item not in s[:i]:
        d.append(i)
        i += 1
    else:
        d.append(s.index(item))
```

Now you get a list where each digit is a unique representation of words in s:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the part where you check if the word is in s. You should save your words in another list and check if the s word is already in the other list. Like in the code below:

```
#for loop makes sure that if the word is in the list then it wont print it out again
    new_s = []
    for word in s:
       if word not in new_s:
           new_s.append(word)
```